# Why am I getting a 500 error when trying to post file URL into DB?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I can't figure out why I'm getting a 500 error when trying to post file URL into the DB.  In my logs, it's saying that my controller doesn't exist, but it does.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Note: I'm using `valet open` to run the project.  I've tried to switch it up and use `php artisan serve` but I still get the same error.

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileuploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        if($request->get('file')) {
            $image = $request->get('file');
            $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
            \Image::make($request->get('file'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);
        }

        $fileupload = new Fileupload();
        $fileupload->filename=$name;
        $fileupload->save();

        return response()->json('Successfully added');
    }
}
```

Here are my routes:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/', 'FileuploadController@store');
```

Here's my post request (react.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class FileUploadComponent extends Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            image: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
    }

    onFormSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.image);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.createImage(files[0]);
    }

    createImage(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                image: e.target.result
            })
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    fileUpload() {
        const url = '/';
        axios.post(url).then(response => {
            console.log(response);

            this.setState({
                file: this.state.image
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <h1>React js Laravel File Upload Tutorial</h1>
                <input type="file"  onChange={this.onChange} />
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Here's the error in the logs:

```
local.ERROR: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\FileuploadController.php] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Http\\Controllers\\FileuploadController.php] does not exist. at /Users/user/workstation/reactlaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:806)
```

Comment: since when do class names end with `.php`? ;)

Comment: @lagbox woops!! I didn't even notice that, careless mistake on my end.  I removed `.php` but I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: try `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: @IGP tried that, getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure it has nothing to do with a typo? Or having the filename be different than the class's name? Have you tried to declare the route as `Route::post('/', '\App\Http\Controllers\FileuploadController@store');`

Comment: @IGP tried that already, getting the same error.

Comment: Add `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` to controller